# Compiling error with python/c++ using swig

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am trying to wrap c++ code to python with numpy using swig and a setup-file. I created a rather simple swig file and a setup.py, but when I run (on Windows XP)

```
python setup.py build -c mingw32
```

compilation of the shared library fails. I have no clue why, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.
What happens is this:
The setup-skript runs swig as it should, and a wrapped goldstein_wrap.cpp is created. Then MinGW is called, and it fails:

> C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Programme\Python27\include -IC:\Programme\Python27\PC -c > goldstein_wrap.cpp -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\goldstein_wrap.o -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
>
> In file included from C:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ arrayobject.h:14:0,
>
> ```
>             from goldstein_wrap.cpp:3059:
> ```
>
> C:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:10:1:
>
> Fehler: expected initializer before »extern«
>
> goldstein_wrap.cpp:2954:25: Warnung: »swig_module« definiert, aber nicht verwendet
>
> [-Wunused-variable]
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

My swig file looks like this:

```
%module goldstein

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "goldstein.h"
%}

/*include numpy typemaps*/
%include "numpy.i"

/*initialize module*/
%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%rename(unwrap2d) phase_unwrapping_func;

/* typemaps for the arrays*/
%apply (int DIM1,int DIM2,float* IN_ARRAY2) {(int ysize,int xsize,float* in)};
%apply (int DIM1,int DIM2,unsigned short* IN_ARRAY2) {(int y1,int x1,unsigned short* mask)};
%apply (int DIM1,int DIM2,float* INPLACE_ARRAY2) {(int y2,int x2,float* out),
                                          (int y3,int x3,float* bcuts),
                                          (int y4,int x4,float* res),
                                          (int y5,int x5,float* diff)}


%inline %{
void phase_unwrapping_func(int ysize,int xsize,float* in,int y1,int x1,
                unsigned short* mask,int y2,int x2,float* out, int y3,int x3,
                float* bcuts,int y4,int x4,float* res, int y5,int x5,float* diff) 
{
    phase_unwrapping(xsize, ysize, in, mask, out, bcuts, res, diff);
}
%}
```

And to give really all information, my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

import numpy

try:
    np_include = numpy.get_include()
except AttributeError:
    np_include = numpy.get_numpy_include()

_goldstein = Extension('_goldstein',
                       ['goldstein.i','goldstein.cpp'],
                       include_dirs=[np_include],   #include python dll
                       swig_opts=['-c++'],  #enable c++ wrapping
                       extra_compile_args=["-static-libgcc",
                                           "-static-libstdc++"],
                       )

setup(name='goldstein',
      version='1.1',
      description='Blubb',
      author='Foo',
      ext_modules = [_goldstein]
      )
```

And, as demanded, the mentioned lines of the swig-generated file:
Lines 2950 to 2958:

```
/* -------- TYPES TABLE (BEGIN) -------- */

#define SWIGTYPE_p_char swig_types[0]
static swig_type_info *swig_types[2];
static swig_module_info swig_module = {swig_types, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
#define SWIG_TypeQuery(name) SWIG_TypeQueryModule(&swig_module, &swig_module, name)
#define SWIG_MangledTypeQuery(name) SWIG_MangledTypeQueryModule(&swig_module, &swig_module, name)

/* -------- TYPES TABLE (END) -------- */
```

And lines 3051 to 3060:

```
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "goldstein.h"


#ifndef SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#  define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY
#endif
#include "stdio.h"
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>


void phase_unwrapping_func(int ysize,int xsize,float* in,int y1,int x1,
                           unsigned short* mask,int y2,int x2,float* out,
                           int y3,int x3,float* bcuts,int y4,int x4,float* res,
                           int y5,int x5,float* diff) 
{
        phase_unwrapping(xsize, ysize, in, mask, out, bcuts, res, diff);
}
```

Line 3059 is the one including numpy/arrayobject.h. Sorry, I should have thought about that earlier...

Comment: We need to see the SWIG generated file, `goldstein_wrap.cpp`, a few of the lines leading up to line 3059

Comment: Of course, I added the specific lines

Comment: The compiler seems to be getting into trouble by the `stdio.h` file. That is supposed to be a standard C header though, it would be unusual but maybe there is another file with the same same in your include path. Otherwise, I would suspect something wrong in `goldstein.h`.

Comment: Perhaps change the order of the #includes a bit and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint towards the headerfile, it was a typo in the last line of that file.